# How to install my download program to the system meun on GNOME 3.14?

Tags: software-installation, thunderbird

I do not mean I want to `make install` the `tar.bz` program, I already downloaded a executable binary program - `thunderbird-31.4.0.tar.bz2`, if you ask, and I can click it and run. But the thing is how can I install it to the sys menu, or GNOME Shell I don't what it called, just like the system default program and the program installed through Ubuntu Software Centre.

Answer (score 0):

Once the application is opened, it'll show up in the dash (the bar to the right of your screen).  Right-click the icon and click "Lock to Launcher")

Have a look at [How to Install Software on Ubuntu for a Windows User](https://askubuntu.com/a/575161/344926) as well as this might help you too!

Comment: And as you're a reputation 21 user who's *never accepted an answer*: If this all works, don't forget to click the grey check-mark under the "0" at the left of this text, which means "yes, this answer is valid"!  ;-)  and if you *really like* the answer, click on the grey arrow above it which means "this is a *great* answer!"...